# grep remote machine with ] character

Tags: bash

I am trying to search a file in remote server.
The pattern I am looking for is `] LEADER`, e.g. `[T2] LEADER` matches.
My command is: `ssh myname@ip grep -r "] LEADER" logfile` 
However, the error `grep : LEADER: no such file` is reported. 
May I know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The shell aborbs the double quotes, so the "grep" on the remote machine sees three arguments - "]", "LEADER" and "logfile"

Change to:
   ssh myname@ip grep -r "\"] LEADER \"" logfile

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes around the command to prevent the command from being interpreted beforehand by the local shell:

```
ssh myname@ip 'grep -r "] LEADER" logfile'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
ssh myname@ip 'grep -r "] LEADER" logfile'
```

It shall escape the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

SSH bundles its arguments together (badly) to create a shell command-line.  So you'll want to quote this command:

```
ssh user@host 'grep -r "\] LEADER" logfile'
```

If you have trouble, it's worth using `ssh -v` to show what it's passing to the remote shell.